# Annoying unison.log on Mac OS X home

Tags: macos, gui, unison

Unison GUI for OS X keeps creating a "unison.log" file in my home directory.

That's retarded, it should either hide the file (".unison.log"), or place it in a proper place, not in my home directory.

Do you know any way to prevent it from doing so? (without having to hack the source and recompile)

I could only come up with a daemon that checks for that file and deletes it, but maybe there are better ways...

Comment: I hate to say this but could you be a bit more careful in how you phrase your questions.  I can't imagine it helps getting good answers to your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The location of the log file can be set in your profile file (typically `~/.unison/something.prf` but as you're on OS X it will be in `~/Library/Application Support/Unison/` ) by adding a line `logfile = /path/to/log/file`. It can also be overridden on the command line with the `-logfile` option.

Generally, if a program doesn't behave in the way you want, I suggest looking for a configuration option before thinking up complex workarounds or modifying the source code. The documentation is your friend. In this case, searching “unison.log” in the documentation would have lead you immediately to the `logfile` preference.

Comment: thanks. It's still quite annoying to have to add it to multiple configuration file instead of just one, but it works...

Comment: You don't have to add it to multiple config files.  I have a global 'default.prf' with settings like "times=true" that I include using 'include default' in all other files (even works hierarchically, which I use for server-specific defaults).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `logfile` option, you might be interested in `log=false`, which disables logging completely.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the log file on the command line as follows

```
-logfile /dev/null
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend sending an email to the developers of the application, or if it is open source, download Xcode and the program source, modify the offending file path, and compile your own "fork" of Unison.